# Camera dialog not saving exif data?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

The following code will open the camera intent and create and read from a temporary jpg file. Upon displaying the picture file back, no matter which way I took the picture, the orientation is always horizontal so I have to hold the phone in landscape to take a normal photo everytime and I don't want that. Is there a solution to changing the photo to normal orientation when I take it that way?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ivPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
    myFilesDir = new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.garrenkeith.faceify/files");
    System.out.println (myFilesDir);
    myFilesDir.mkdirs();
}

public void TakePhoto(View v){
    Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(myFilesDir.toString()+"/temp.jpg")));
    startActivityForResult(camIntent, 0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==0){
        try {

            Bitmap cameraBitmap;
            cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFilesDir + "/temp.jpg");
            Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap);
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a file name onto the intent to save the image to the file. try this code:

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, 0);
    activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
```

In this case, if the rotation can't work, you can get EXIF information from the file in `onActivityResult`.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f);
String rotation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int rotation = Integer.valueOf(rotation);
```

Then, try to rotate the bitmap